# How to remove consecutive upper case characters from a text in r?

Tags: r, text-mining

For example I have a text

```
a <- "This IS A SAMple sentence TMP"
```

I want the output to be as:

```
"This A ple sentence"
```

How do i do it? Some easier way to do this?

Comment: Easier than what? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried running a for loop looking for upper case at consecutive positions or more but that is becoming too complicated because there can be more than 2 consecutive upper case characters too.

Comment: Become familiar with regex - see `?regex` and, e.g., www.regular-expressions.info - they will serve you well for all manner of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  library(stringr)
  str_trim(gsub("[A-Z]{2,}","",a))
  [1] "This  A ple sentence"
```

Comment: The answer is good.  Perhaps an explanation of the components would supplement it.  First, gsub looks globally in a for any string that has capital letters -- which is the character class [A-Z] -- two or more times in a row -- which is the quantifier {2, }.  If the quantifier were {2,3} it would look for two in a row or three in a row; if {2} it would look for exactly two in a row.  When gsub finds those matches it replaces them with blanks, as with "".  Finally, str_trim removes blank spaces at the start of the end.